# Функция получает массив и его размер. Проверяет возможность существования элемента x, a[1]<x<a[n] ,если true 1,иначе 0. Необходимая сложность O(1)

Tags: c

Функция получает **массив** и его **размер**. Проверяет возможность существования элемента **x**,
**a[1]<x<a[n]** ,если true **1**,иначе **0**. Необходимая сложность **O(1)**.

Я хотел решить так, но преподаватель запретил передавать val:

```
int isPossible(int A[], int size, int val)
{
    if (val > A[1] && val < A[size - 1])
    {
        if (A[size - 1] - A[0] >= size)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Спасибо:)

Comment: А можете привести точную, дословно, формулировку задачи? В данном варианте запрет преподавателя выглядит для меня странно..

Comment: Недостаточно данных вы привели. Что значит `проверяет возможность`? Массив `int`, число тоже `int` - значит число может быть в нем. Ваши проверки работают только если массив отсортирован и числа в нем находящиеся, сгенерированы последовательно и не повторяются. Например 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... n И почему `if (val > A[1] `? А если проверяемое число равно `A[1]`? Насчет запрета передавать `val` - очень странно, оно же является одним из условий задачи. Чтобы формально выполнить это требование можете сделать её глобальной.

Comment: мда.... Сделать глобальной даже мысль не пришла.... Что значит, сила привычки.

Comment: Тут не просто надо посмотреть разность первого и последнего элементов - чтоб она была больше 1, т.е. можно было вставить элемент между ними?